# MongoDB: Using update method to add an new element of an array doesn't work

Tags: mongodb

I used mongodb's udpate method to change an array's element, I hoped to add a new element, but it changed the first one instead of adding an new one.
However if I use updateOne it's OK. It's update's bug or I made a mistake. Thanks for your help!
What I had done was as the following.

```
1.db.test.insertOne({a:[{b:1,c:2}]});

2.db.test.find({}) returns:
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc593001b800790b21afa62"), 
    "a" : [
        {
            "b" : 1.0, 
            "c" : 2.0
        }
    ]
}

3. db.test.update({_id:ObjectId("5fc593001b800790b21afa62")}, 
[{
    $set:
    {"a.1": 
        {a:3, b:30}
    }
 }])
4)db.test.find({}) returns: 
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc593001b800790b21afa62"), 
    "a" : [
        {
            "b" : 1.0, 
            "c" : 2.0, 
            "1" : {
                "a" : 3.0, 
                "b" : 30.0
            }
        }
    ]
}
It seems wrong, and it should be like { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc593001b800790b21afa62"), 
    "a" : [
        {
            "b" : 1.0, 
            "c" : 2.0
        },
        {
            "a" : 3.0, 
          "b" : 30.0
        }
    ]
}, do I make a mistake? However, if I use updateOne, it works.
5) Instead of update method, execute:
db.test.updateOne({_id:ObjectId("5fc593001b800790b21afa62")}, 
{
    $set:
    {"a.1": 
        {a:3, b:30}
    }
 })
6) db.test.find({}) returns: 
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc593001b800790b21afa62"), 
    "a" : [
        {
            "b" : 1.0, 
            "c" : 2.0
        }, 
        {
            "a" : 3.0, 
            "b" : 30.0
        }
    ]
}
It's what I want.
```

I think they should do the same thing, Do I misunderstand? And how should I do to make it work? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use `$push` to add an element to an array.

Comment: I can't, because it's probably that a[1] already exists, I just want to update a[1].

Comment: I think you need to understand that the update of an array can be achieved using a _regular update_ or an _aggregation update_. In step 3 you are using an aggregation update. In step 5 it is a regular update.